# sending email per intent => is there a length limit?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I've written a function, for sending an email via intent. On my phone, gmail is installed, so the first part of this function is used... I want to send my database as a csv file, so it's quite a big string. If I send all data at once, NOTHING happens (no exception, no mail program that appears). If I split my data into two parts and send them one after another, it works. So there seems to be a limitation for the text.

Does anyone know what the limit is? Or is there another problem I'm not aware of?

```
public static void sendMailWithIntent(Activity activity, String subject, String text, boolean textIsHtml, String receiver)
{
    try
    {
        Intent sendMailtoGmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendMailtoGmail.setType("plain/text");
        sendMailtoGmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
                receiver
        });
        sendMailtoGmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        sendMailtoGmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textIsHtml ? Html.fromHtml(text) : text);
        sendMailtoGmail.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendMailtoGmail, ""));
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Intent sendGeneric = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendGeneric.setType("plain/text");
        sendGeneric.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
                receiver
        });
        sendGeneric.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        sendGeneric.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textIsHtml ? Html.fromHtml(text) : text);
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendGeneric, ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a 1MB limit imposed by the IPC mechanism, and individual mail clients (of which there are *many*) are welcome to impose other limits. For something big, use an attachment. Also note that `plain/text` is not a valid MIME type.

Comment: ok, thanks, that explains the issue